# What is happening when I type 'zsh -manual' in my Zsh shell?

Tags: command-line-interface, zsh, oh-my-zsh

When I type: `zsh -manual` and press enter my command line moves down to another line with `%` prepending the blank space. I then cannot exit out of the "mode" my Zsh is running in to return to the Zsh prompt. Can someone please explain what typing `Zsh -manual` does?

When I get stuck in the `%` mode I have tried `ctrl + x`, `ctrl + c`, `ctrl + q`, and every other `ctrl + <character>` I could think of.

// In Zsh shell type:

```
~ zsh -manual
```

Press `return`. You should see:

```
%
```

Just a simple explanation is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-manual` is just the single-letter options `-m`, `-a`, `-n`, `-u`, `-a`, `-l` combined.

- `-m` turns on job monitoring, which is on by default for interactive shells anyway, so no effect.
- `-a` exports all variables when they're set.
- `-n` (aka `noexec`) **turns off execution of commands**. Commands are only checked for syntax errors. This effectively makes all the other options irrelevant.
- `-u` makes expansion of unset variables an error
- `-l` starts a login shell.

So you just started a new shell that doesn't run any commands (which is probably why the prompt is just the default `%`). You could get the same effect by using just `zsh -n`.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I did. So my follow-up question is how do I exit a new shell that doesn't run any commands?